# Can anybody explain why App insights are visible for Deleted Pod?

Tags: azure-application-insights, kubernetes-pod

Azure app insights is still showing insights for a older pod which is already deleted in a cluster instead of the newer pod  .
Does anybody know how to refresh App insights configuration in order to show App insights for the newer pod instead of the older one.

Comment: Do you mean that new data is still ingested, like the pod is still running or do you mean the history is still visible?

Comment: new data is still ingested , the pod is still running

Comment: If you delete a single pod it might very well be recreated due to deployment configuration. Could that be the issue?

Comment: Basically the thing is I have created the new pod and deleted the older one , so the  new pod should run instead of the older one and app insights should show data of the newer pod .So want to know whether we can do anything to refresh AI configuration